# SSIS, outputting null as a column value within a script task

Tags: ssis

I have a synchronous transformation script component, with some input columns, and an extra defined Output column "ID". ID outputs an integer (DT_I4) type. Under certain circumstances, I would like "ID" to output a null value from my script.

Assigning it a null value in other SSIS components works, I can use NULL(DT_I4) within a derived column for example, but I cannot figure out how to do this in a script.

```
Row.ID = null;
```

claims that ID is not a nullable value type.

I use c# within my scripts.

Is there any way to do this?

Edit: To make life easier, "ID" would ideally output a value of `NULL` by default if it is not assigned anywhere within the script using `Row.ID = ...;`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Every column has a booelan property called ColumnName_IsNull (in your case should be Row.ID_IsNull). I think you should set it to true to set the columns value NULL

Comment: Excellent, just the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: That didn't work for me, all I get back is false, but i don't get the lines where there is a text or numeric value expected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72149895/ssis-null-values-on-a-integer-in-script-compontent